# AngularJs $resource.query() gives TypeError: href is null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am using angular $resource.query to retrieve json data over REST. When I call the query() method a GET request is sent to the server and successfully retrieves the json data:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/competitors{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "competitors" : [ {
      "name" : "sdfdfsdf",
      "tagline" : null,
      "url" : null,
      "active" : true,
      "itemId" : 4,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/competitors/4"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "aaaaa",
      "tagline" : null,
      "url" : null,
      "active" : true,
      "itemId" : 12,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/competitors/12"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

but it then immediately throws this js error:

```
TypeError: href is null
consoleLog/<()angular.js (line 12477)
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<()angular.js (line 9246)
processQueue()angular.js (line 14753)
scheduleProcessQueue/<()angular.js (line 14761)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval()angular.js (line 15989)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest()angular.js (line 15800)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply()angular.js (line 16097)
done()angular.js (line 10546)
completeRequest()angular.js (line 10744)
requestLoaded()angular.js (line 10685)


stackFrame.js (line 357)
```

Here is the relevant js code:

```
    $scope.Competitor = $resource("/competitors/:id", {id: "@id"});

    $scope.listItems = function () {
        var query = $scope.Competitor.query();
        query.$promise.then(
            function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.competitors = data._embedded.competitors;
            },
            function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log('error:');
                console.dir(data);
            }
        );
    };
```

After the error, the errorCallback function is executed, but the value of data is null.

I've tried this with angular-1.4.7 and angular-1.2.27

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: create a demo that replicates this. Can create data file and use `$resource` in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Firebug is obscuring the true error when you see: TypeError: href is null   try a different browser or open the firefox developer tools instead of firebug. Strange but true.

Comment: i also have this kind of bug. thanks to @ahmeij  for his response. i try with firefox developper edition and the bug error is more comprehensive

Comment: Thank you @ahmeij, you are right, firebug was hiding the real error. Which was: Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object (Request: GET /competitors). I was able to fix this by initing the $resource handler for query with isArray: true.

Comment: @ahmeij if you had posted that in an answer, I would have upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

As requested in a comment, here is my comment as an answer:

Firebug is obscuring the true error when you see: TypeError: href is null try a different browser or open the firefox developer tools instead of firebug.